# Proper JSON to include when using Drupal Services 3, File Resource

Tags: drupal, rest

I understand the Drupal Services Module, and have node creation, and user authentication working.  I am trying to upload a file (an image) from android that will populate a node image field.  My understanding of Services is pretty good.  I have enabled the file resource in my service.  I assume to create the file, I will POST my data to my-server/service-endpoint/create.  The big question I can't find anywhere is what data is needed, and what is the structure of the JSON that I will send since I will be using JSON as the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple this one.. The data is here...
http://drupanium.org/api/82

Then just recreate the array they list as a JSON object.. only required parameter is file.. so
{"file":FILE_NAME}

The correct url is www.my-site.com/[REST-ENDPOINT]/file and then POST the data.

Answer (score 1):

The above link (i.e: http://drupanium.org/api/82) is correct except that the filename is not optional but required...

Service kept on returning "Missing Data The file can not be uploaded" until I added the "filename" attribute to the request

Comment: Can you post a working example inline with your answer in addition to the link?